# How to select a specific off-diagonal band from a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose an `NxN` square matrix. I would like to select a band of width `w` which is offset by `k` to the main diagonal as shown in the following example for `N = 9, w = 4, k = -1`

[image]

The ordering of elements should be as for [`np.tril_indices(N, k=k)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html). So basically the corresponding indices should be `np.tril_indices(N, k=k)` reduced by `np.tril_indices(N, k=k-w)`:

```
i1 = list(zip(*np.tril_indices(N, k=k)))
i2 = list(zip(*np.tril_indices(N, k=k-w)))
indices = tuple(zip(*[i for i in i1 if i not in i2]))
M[indices]
```

Or alternatively using [`np.tril`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) which however stores the full matrix as an intermediary result and only works for 2D arrays:

```
B = np.ravel(np.tril(M, k=k) - np.tril(M, k=k-w))
B[B.nonzero()]
```

I'm wondering whether there is a more effective and/or more concise way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
In [19]: np.tri(6,6, dtype=bool)
Out[19]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Combining 2 `tri` masks:

```
In [22]: np.tri(6,6, dtype=bool)&~np.tri(6,6,-3,dtype=bool)
Out[22]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True]])

In [23]: np.where(Out[22])
Out[23]: 
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]),
 array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5]))
```

`np.tri` is essentially:

```
In [29]: np.greater_equal.outer(np.arange(4),np.arange(4))
Out[29]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
In [30]: np.greater_equal(np.arange(4)[:,None],np.arange(4))
Out[30]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

`np.tril` just applies `where` to this.

```
In [37]: np.greater_equal(np.arange(4)[:,None], np.arange(4)) & 
         np.less_equal(np.arange(-1,3)[:,None], np.arange(4))
Out[37]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True]])
```